# What is the quickest way to get a trapezohedron?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

They're 2M when bought - is there a faster way to gain/earn/find a trapezohedron other than grinding for the gil necessary to buy it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are patient, and don't mind getting really bored... Setup Vanille as your party leader, preferably with the Improved Debuffing weapon, and a whole lot of haste.  Pick a fight with the big adamantoise right outside the Eden Palace, immediately summon your Eidelon to take out the legs, then send the eidelon home and spam the Death spell.  I usually setup the other two party members as synergists to quickly pickup haste and faith.

Interestingly enough - I killed this guy before I ever walked into the Eden Palace, and he never crashed through the glass, it let me loot both treasure spheres located right there!

[Some more tips for this technique](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/32228/t1499775-adamantoise-farming-for-low-level-characters/) can be found online.

Comment: Spamming death on those things made a good 2 or 3 days for me and my gf in the plains...took for-ev-er.

Comment: By the time you get higher in levels, you can just beast them down faster than you would death them.

Answer (score 0):

You can always grind Tortoises and hope for many 60k item drops. Either way I guess it will take some time.

Kr